Вообщем, я не могу добавить кнопку назад которая используется почти во всех клавиатурах
func.py
from aiogram import F, Router, types
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command
from aiogram.types import Message, InputFile
import keybord as kb
from ma import loaded_data
import link
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


router = Router()


@router.message(CommandStart())
async def start(message: Message):
    await message.answer(f"""
    Добро пожаловать, {message.from_user.first_name}!
    Қош келдіңіз {message.from_user.first_name}!""",
                         reply_markup=kb.main)

@router.message(F.text == 'Русский язык')
async def russ(message:Message):
    await message.answer('Выберите одну из категорий',
                         reply_markup=kb.russ)

@router.message(F.text == 'Поступающим')
async def postyp(message:Message):
    await message.answer('Выберите одну из категорий',
                         reply_markup=kb.postyp)

def get_news(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BS(response.text, 'html.parser')

    news_container = soup.find('div', {'class': 'grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 pb-6'})
    news_items = news_container.find_all('a', {'class': 'flex flex-col sm:h-48 rounded-md sm:grid grid-cols-3 shadow-lg flex-grow my-3 mx-3 cursor-pointer bg-white hover:shadow-2xl transition duration-500'})[:5]

    return news_items


@router.message(F.text == 'Новости')
async def news(message: types.Message):
    news_items = get_news('https://iitu.edu.kz/ru/news/')
    for i in range(3):
        news = news_items[i]
        title = news.find('div', {'class': 'text-gray-900 font-bold text-xl mb-2'}).text.strip()
        time = news.find('p', {'class': 'text-gray-700 text-base'}).text.strip()
        img_url = news.find('img')['src']
        link = news['href'] if news else "Ссылка недоступна"
        await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz' + img_url, caption=f"{title}\n{time}\nСсылка: {link}")

@router.message(F.text == 'ИИ(скоро)')
async def ai(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Здесь планируется создание ИИ для различных задач')

@router.message(F.text == 'Мероприятия(скоро)')
async def Events(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Здесь планируется отображение списка мероприятий, в ближайшее время')

@router.message(F.text == 'Расписание(скоро)')
async def Schedule(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Здесь планируется отображение рассписания по группам')

@router.message(F.text == 'Баллы ЕНТ')
async def ball_ent(message: Message):
    await message.answer(f"{loaded_data['ENT']}", reply_to_message_id=message.message_id, parse_mode="HTML")

@router.message(F.text == 'Воен.кафедра')
async def voen_kaf(message: Message):
    await message.answer(f"{loaded_data['ARMY']}", parse_mode="html")

@router.message(F.text == 'Cписок документов для подачи')
async def dok_dlu_padachi(message: Message):
    await message.answer(f"{loaded_data['DOCUMENTS']}",
                         reply_to_message_id=message.message_id, parse_mode="html")

@router.message(F.text == ' Адрес ')
async def adres(message: Message):
    await message.answer(f"{loaded_data['ADDRES']}",
                         parse_mode="MARKDOWN")
    await message.answer_location(43.235381, 76.909684)

@router.message(F.text == 'Договор для платного отделения')
async def dog_plat_ot(message: Message):
    await message.answer('https://iitu.edu.kz/documents/2441/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5'
            '%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0'
            '%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F.pdf')

@router.message(F.text == '% Скидки %')
async def skidki(message: Message):
    await message.answer('/Razer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/itu/content/положение_об_оплате_и_предоставлению_скидок_за_обучение.pdf')

@router.message(F.text == '❗Группы образовательных программ❗')
async def group_obraz_prog(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Выберите одну из категорий',
                         reply_markup=kb.group_obraz_prog)

@router.message(F.text == 'B042 Журналистика и репортерское дело')
async def Journalism_and_reporting(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Выберите одну из категорий',
                         reply_markup=kb.Journalism_and_reporting)

@router.message(F.text == '6B03201 БИЗНЕС-ЖУРНАЛИСТИКА, SMM & PR')
async def BUSINESS_JOURNALISM(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/44_zITuB16.original.jpg'),
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/00_Montazhnaia_oblast_1_kopiia_10.original.png')

@router.message(F.text == '6B03202 ЦИФРОВАЯ ЖУРНАЛИСТИКА')
async def DIGITAL_JOURNALISM(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/00_Montazhnaia_oblast_1_kopiia_113.original.png')
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/00_Montazhnaia_oblast_1_kopiia_11.original.png')

@router.message(F.text == '6B03203 МЕЖДУНАРОДНАЯ ЖУРНАЛИСТИКА')
async def INTERNATIONAL_JOURNALISM(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo(photo='international_jour.jpg')

@router.message(F.text == '6B03204 ТЕЛЕРАДИОЖУРНАЛИСТИКА')
async def TELEVISION_RADIO_JOURNALISM(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/00_Montazhnaia_oblast_1_kopiia_12.original.png')

# @router.message(F.text == 'Вернуться к обр.группам')
# async def Back_to_arr_groups(message:Message):
#     await message.answer()

@router.message(F.text == ' Назад')
async def handle_back_button(message: Message):
    current_text = message.text


@router.message(F.text == 'B044 Менедмент и управление')
async def Management_Control(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Выберите одну из категорий',
                         reply_markup=kb.Management_Control)

@router.message(F.text == '6B04103 ИННОВАЦИОННЫЙ МЕНЕДЖМЕНТ')
async def INNOVATION_MANAGEMENT(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/OP_Montazhnaia_oblast_1_kopiia_8.original.jpg'),
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/OP_Montazhnaia_oblast_1.original.jpg')

@router.message(F.text == '6B04102 ЭЛЕКТРОННЫЙ БИЗНЕС')
async def ELECTRONIC_BUSINESS(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/Obrazets_str.1.original.jpg'),
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/Obrazets_str.2.original.jpg')

@router.message(F.text == 'В046 Финансы, экономика,банковское и страховое дело')
async def Finance_economics_banking_insurance(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Выберите одну из категорий',
                         reply_markup=kb.Finance_economics_banking_insurance)

@router.message(F.text == '6B04104 ФИНАНСОВЫЙ ИНЖИНИРИНГ')
async def FINANCIAL_ENGINEERING(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/OP_Montazhnaia_oblast_1_kopiia_5.original.jpg'),
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/OP_Montazhnaia_oblast_1_kopiia_4.original.jpg')

@router.message(F.text == '6B04105 ФИНАНСОВЫЕ ТЕХНОЛОГИИ')
async def FINANCIAL_TECHNOLOGY(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/OP_Montazhnaia_oblast_1_kopiia_3.original.jpg'),
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/OP_Montazhnaia_oblast_1_kopiia.original.jpg')

@router.message(F.text == 'B057 Информационные технологии')
async def Information_technology(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Выберите одну из категорий',
                         reply_markup=kb.Information_technology)

@router.message(F.text == '6B06101 КОМПЬЮТЕРНЫЕ НАУКИ')
async def COMPUTER_SCIENCES(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/00_Montazhnaia_oblast_1_kopiia_14.original.png'),
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/00_Montazhnaia_oblast_1_kopiia_15.original.png')

@router.message(F.text == '6B06103 АНАЛИТИКА БОЛЬШИХ ДАННЫХ')
async def BIG_DATA_ANALYTICS(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/00_Montazhnaia_oblast_1_kopiia_16.original.png'),
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/00_Montazhnaia_oblast_1_kopiia_17.original.png')

@router.message(F.text == '6B06104 БИЗНЕС-АНАЛИЗ')
async def BUSINESS_ANALYSIS(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/00_Montazhnaia_oblast_1_kopiia_18.original.png'),
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/00_Montazhnaia_oblast_1_kopiia_19.original.png')

@router.message(F.text == '6B06105 ИНФОРМАЦИОННЫЕ СИСТЕМЫ')
async def INFORMATION_SYSTEMS(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/OP_Montazhnaia_oblast_1_kopiia_33.original.png'),
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/OP_Montazhnaia_oblast_1_kopiia_34.original.png')

@router.message(F.text == '6B06106 ВЫЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНАЯ ТЕХНИКА И ПРОГРАММНОЕ ОБЕСПЕЧЕНИЕ')
async def COMPUTER_EQUIPMENT_SOFTWARE(message: Message):
    await message.answer('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKI1KF1e8Bo&ab_channel=ITVeritas'),
    await message.answer(f"{loaded_data['ADDRES']}")

@router.message(F.text == '6B06109 ИММЕРСИВНЫЕ ТЕХНОЛОГИИ')
async def IMMERSIVE_TECHNOLOGIES(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo(photo='')

@router.message(F.text == '6B06110 ПРОГРАММНАЯ ИНЖЕНЕРИЯ')
async def SOFTWARE_ENGINEERING(message: Message):
    photo = InputFile()
    await message.answer_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id)

@router.message(F.text == '6B06111 ФИНАНСОВАЯ МАТЕМАТИКА')
async def FINANCIAL_MATHEMATICS(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/OP_Montazhnaia_oblast_1_kopiia_30.original.png')

@router.message(F.text == '6B06113 ИНЖЕНЕРНАЯ МАТЕМАТИКА')
async def ENGINEERING_MATHEMATICS(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/OP_Montazhnaia_oblast_1_kopiia_32.original.png')

@router.message(F.text == '6B06113 ИНЖЕНЕРНАЯ МАТЕМАТИКА')
async def ENGINEERING_MATHEMATICS(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/OP_Montazhnaia_oblast_1_kopiia_32.original.png')

@router.message(F.text == '6B06114 БИОКОМПЬЮТИНГ')
async def BIOCOMPUTTING(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/111-02.width-800.png')

@router.message(F.text == '6В06119 ИНФОРМАЦИОННЫЕ ТЕХНОЛОГИИ В БИЗНЕСЕ')
async def NFORMATION_TECHNOLOGY_BUSINESS(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/buklet-el-biznesvtoraia.original.png'),
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/buklet-el-biznestretia.original.png'),
    await message.answer_photo(photo='https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/buklet-el-bizneschetvertaia.original.png')

@router.message(F.text == 'B058 Информационная безопасность')
async def Information_security(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Выберите одну из категорий',
                         reply_markup=kb.Information_security)

@router.message(F.text == '6B06302 АППАРАТНЫЕ СРЕДСТВА ЗАЩИТЫ ИНФОРМАЦИИ')
async def INFORMATION_SECURITY_HARDWARE(message: Message):
        photo = InputFile("files/test.png")

@router.message(F.text == '6B06303 СЕТЕВАЯ БЕЗОПАСНОСТЬ')
async def NETWORK_SECURITY(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo(photo='')

@router.message(F.text == '6B06301 КОМПЬЮТЕРНАЯ БЕЗОПАСНОСТЬ')
async def COMPUTER_SECURITY(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo(photo='comp_bez.jpg')

@router.message(F.text == 'B059 Коммуникации и коммуникационные технологии')
async def communication_technologies(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Выберите нужную вам кнопку',
                         reply_markup=kb.communication_technologies)

@router.message(F.text == '6B06203 МОБИЛЬНЫЕ ТЕХНОЛОГИИ И КОММУНИКАЦИИ')
async def MOBILE_TECHNOLOGY(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo('')

@router.message(F.text == '6B06201 ТЕЛЕКОММУНИКАЦИОННЫЕ СИСТЕМЫ И СЕТИ')
async def ELECOMMUNICATION_SYSTEMS_NETWORKS(message: Message):
    await message.answer_photo('https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/OP_Montazhnaia_oblast_1_kopiia_38_bHVjGnl.original.png')

@router.message(F.text == 'Студентам')
async def nazad(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Выберите нужную вам кнопку',
                         reply_markup=kb.student)

@router.message(F.text == 'Связь')
async def contact(message: Message):
    await message.answer(f"{loaded_data['CONNECT_1']}")

@router.message(F.text == 'Информация по кредитам на 2023г')
async def nformation_loans(message: Message):
    await message.answer("На учебный год 2023-2024 для Бакалавриат  <b><u>24000₸</u></b>\n"
                                          "На учебный год 2023-2024, <b><u>28000₸</u></b> Магистратуры",
                          parse_mode="html")

@router.message(F.text == 'Академический\n календарь ')
async def academic_calendar(message: Message):
    await message.answer('https://iitu.edu.kz/documents/2481/%D0%90%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_2022-2023_%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4.pdf_q2XyN0n.pdf')

@router.message(F.text == 'Перевод')
async def translate(message: Message):
    await message.answer(f"{loaded_data['TRANSLATE']}")

@router.message(F.text == 'Местонахождение ключевых мест')
async def location_key_places(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Выбор",
                         reply_markup=kb.location_key_places)

@router.message(F.text == 'Спортзал')
async def sportzal(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Нажмите на адрес и он скопируется: `улица Ауэзова, 145д`"),
    await message.answer_location(43.234855, 76.903831)

@router.message(F.text == 'Военная.к')
async def military_k(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Нажмите на адрес и он скопируется: `Проспект Абая, 52г`"),
    await message.answer_location(43.237601, 76.913306)

@router.message(F.text == 'INO-Center')
async def INO_Center(message: Message):
    await message.answer("INO находиться на 4 этаже главного корпуса университета,у лестницы,со стороны ",
                         "ул.Жандосова,рядом с лифтом,ориентир - стеклянная дверь в большое помещение."),
    await message.answer_location(43.235178, 76.9092958)

@router.message(F.text == 'Кафедры')
async def caf(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Выбор',
                         reply_markup=kb.caf)

@router.message(F.text == 'Кафедра МКМ')
async def caf_mkm(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Кафедра МКМ располагается на 8 этаже,справа от лестницы,со стороны ул.Манаса, 807 кабинет")

@router.message(F.text == 'Кафедра ИС')
async def caf_is(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Кафедра ИС располагается в БЦ 'Байзак', на 4 этаже 427 кабинет")


@router.message(F.text == 'Кафедра Жур')
async def caf_zyr(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Кафедра Журналистики и репортерского дела распологается на втором этаже университета, слева от лестницы,со стороны Уул.Жандосова')

@router.message(F.text == 'Кафедра СИБ')
async def caf_sub(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Кафедра СИБ располагается в БЦ "Байзак", на 4 этаже ближе крылу колледжа')

@router.message(F.text == 'Оплата обучения')
async def banks_ouput(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Выбор',
                         reply_markup=kb.banks_ouput)

@router.message(F.text == 'Kaspi Bank')
async def kaspi(message: Message):
    await message.answer("https://iitu.edu.kz/documents/2442/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B.pdf"),
    await message.answer(f"{loaded_data['KASPI_BANK']}")

@router.message(F.text == 'Halyk Bank')
async def halyk(message: Message):
    await message.answer("https://iitu.edu.kz/documents/2461/%D0%9C%D0%A3%D0%98%D0%A2_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0.pdf"),
    await message.answer(f"{loaded_data['KASPI_BANK']}")

@router.message(F.text == 'BCC Bank')
async def bbs(message: Message):
    await message.answer("https://iitu.edu.kz/documents/2444/%D0%91%D0%A6%D0%9A_spDUVeQ.pdf"),
    await message.answer(f"{loaded_data['BCC_BANK']}")

@router.message(F.text == 'Цены')
async def prices(message: Message):
    await message.answer()

@router.message(F.text == 'Общее')
async def general(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Выберите одну из категорий',
                         reply_markup=kb.general)

@router.message(F.texr == 'Об университете')
async def About_university(message: Message):
    await message.answer('''
Международный технологий ведущее высшее учебное заведение
в Центрально - Азиатском регионе в области подготовки квалифицированных, международно - признанных IT специалистов'''),
    await message.answer_photo("https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/dostizheniia.original.png"),
    await message.answer_photo("https://iitu.edu.kz/media/images/A4_-_1.original.png")

@router.message(F.text == 'Партнеры')
async def partners(message:Message):
    await message.answer(f"{loaded_data['PARTNERS']}", parse_mode="HTML"),


@router.message(F.text == 'РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ В СИСТЕМЕ PLATONUS')
async def registr(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Кнопки ниже - информационные материалы:')
    await message.answer('Кнокпи ниже - ссылки на сайты:',
                         reply_markup=kb.registr)

@router.message(F.text == 'Ссылки')
async def links(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Выберите одну из категорий',
                         reply_markup=kb.links)



keyboard.py
main = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
    keyboard=[
        [KeyboardButton(text='Русский язык'), KeyboardButton(text='Қазақ тілі (Бұл функция әзірленуде)')]
    ],
    resize_keyboard=True
)

russ = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
    keyboard=[
        [KeyboardButton(text='Поступающим'), KeyboardButton(text='Студентам')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='Общее'), KeyboardButton(text='Ссылки')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='Мероприятия(скоро)'), KeyboardButton(text='Расписание(скоро)')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='ИИ(скоро)'), KeyboardButton(text='Новости')]
    ],
    resize_keyboard=True
)

postyp = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
    keyboard=[
        [KeyboardButton(text='Баллы ЕНТ'), KeyboardButton(text='Воен.кафедра')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='Cписок документов для подачи'), KeyboardButton(text=' Адрес ')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='Договор для платного отделения'), KeyboardButton(text='% Скидки %')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='❗Группы образовательных программ❗'), KeyboardButton(text='РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ В СИСТЕМЕ PLATONUS')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='Назад')]
    ],
    resize_keyboard=True
)

group_obraz_prog = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
    keyboard=[
        [KeyboardButton(text='B042 Журналистика и репортерское дело')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='B044 Менеджмент и управление')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='В046 Финансы, экономика, банковское и страховое дело')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='B057 Информационные технологии')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='B058 Информационная безопасность')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='B059 Коммуникации и коммуникационные технологии')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='Назад')]
    ],
    resize_keyboard=True
)

student = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
    keyboard=[
        [KeyboardButton(text='Связь'), KeyboardButton(text='Воен.кафедра')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='Информация по кредитам на 2023г'), KeyboardButton(text='Академический календарь ')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='Местонахождение ключевых мест'), KeyboardButton(text='Перевод')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='Оплата обучения')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='Назад')]
    ],
    resize_keyboard=True
)

Journalism_and_reporting = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
    keyboard=[
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B03201 БИЗНЕС-ЖУРНАЛИСТИКА, SMM & PR')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B03202 ЦИФРОВАЯ ЖУРНАЛИСТИКА')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B03203 МЕЖДУНАРОДНАЯ ЖУРНАЛИСТИКА')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B03204 ТЕЛЕРАДИОЖУРНАЛИСТИКА')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='Вернуться к обр.группам')]
    ],
    resize_keyboard=True
)

Management_Control = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
    keyboard=[
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B04103 ИННОВАЦИОННЫЙ МЕНЕДЖМЕНТ')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B04102 ЭЛЕКТРОННЫЙ БИЗНЕС')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='Вернуться к обр.группам')]
    ],
    resize_keyboard=True
)

Finance_economics_banking_insurance = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
    keyboard=[
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B04104 ФИНАНСОВЫЙ ИНЖИНИРИНГ')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B04105 ФИНАНСОВЫЕ ТЕХНОЛОГИИ')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='Вернуться к обр.группам')]
    ],
    resize_keyboard=True
)

Information_technology = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
    keyboard=[
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B06101 КОМПЬЮТЕРНЫЕ НАУКИ')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B06103 АНАЛИТИКА БОЛЬШИХ ДАННЫХ')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B06104 БИЗНЕС-АНАЛИЗ')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B06105 ИНФОРМАЦИОННЫЕ СИСТЕМЫ')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B06106 ВЫЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНАЯ ТЕХНИКА И ПРОГРАММНОЕ ОБЕСПЕЧЕНИЕ')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B06109 ИММЕРСИВНЫЕ ТЕХНОЛОГИИ')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B06110 ПРОГРАММНАЯ ИНЖЕНЕРИЯ')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B06111 ФИНАНСОВАЯ МАТЕМАТИКА')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B06113 ИНЖЕНЕРНАЯ МАТЕМАТИКА')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B06114 БИОКОМПЬЮТИНГ')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='6В06119 ИНФОРМАЦИОННЫЕ ТЕХНОЛОГИИ В БИЗНЕСЕ')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='Вернуться к обр.группам')]
    ],
    resize_keyboard=True
)

Information_security = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
    keyboard=[
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B06302 АППАРАТНЫЕ СРЕДСТВА ЗАЩИТЫ ИНФОРМАЦИИ')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B06303 СЕТЕВАЯ БЕЗОПАСНОСТЬ')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B06301 КОМПЬЮТЕРНАЯ БЕЗОПАСНОСТЬ')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='Вернуться к обр.группам')]
    ],
    resize_keyboard=True
)

communication_technologies = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
    keyboard=[
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B06203 МОБИЛЬНЫЕ ТЕХНОЛОГИИ И КОММУНИКАЦИИ')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='6B06201 ТЕЛЕКОММУНИКАЦИОННЫЕ СИСТЕМЫ И СЕТИ')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='Вернуться к обр.группам')]
    ],
    resize_keyboard=True
)

location_key_places = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
    keyboard=[
        [KeyboardButton(text='Спортзал')], [KeyboardButton(text='Военная.к')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='INO-Center')], [KeyboardButton(text='Кафедры')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='Назад')]
    ],
    resize_keyboard=True
)

caf = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
    keyboard=[
        [KeyboardButton(text='Кафедра МКМ')], [KeyboardButton(text='Кафедра ИС')], [KeyboardButton(text='Кафедра СИБ')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='Кафедра Жур')], [KeyboardButton(text='Назад')]
    ],
    resize_keyboard=True
)

banks_ouput = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
    keyboard=[
        [KeyboardButton(text='Kaspi Bank')], [KeyboardButton(text='Halyk Bank')], [KeyboardButton(text='Цены')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='BCC Bank')], [KeyboardButton(text='Назад')]
    ],
    resize_keyboard=True
)

general = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
    keyboard=[
        [KeyboardButton(text='Об университете')], [KeyboardButton(text='Аккредитация ')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='Партнеры')], [KeyboardButton(text='Социальные сети')],
        [KeyboardButton(text='Назад')]
    ],
    resize_keyboard=True
)


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
